# Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь освоить php по урокам [отсюда](http://archive-ipq-co.narod.ru/l1/arrays.html) и застопорилась на решении задачи 3. Пыталась сделать так:

```
error_reporting(-1);

$answers = array(
    1 => 'Да',
    2 => 'Нет',
    3 => 'Не знаю',
    4 => 'Никогда',
    5 => 'Зависит от тебя'
    );

$question = 'Выучу ли я ПХП без СМС и регистрации?';
$random = mt_rand (1,4);
$answer = $answers ['$random'];

echo "{$answer}";
```

но в итоге получаю вышеуказанную ошибку. Дайте совет, пожалуйста, что необходимо исправить.

Comment: вы не правильно работаете со строками, уберите кавычки. И почему `1, 4` если у вас 5 вариантов?

Answer (score 0):

суть в кавычках. При одинарных кавычках переменная не подставляется. Следовательно, Вы пытаетесь найти по ключу '$random'. Вам нужно либо убрать кавычки, либо заключить в двойные (но это уже для любителей).

Comment: Спасибо большое, убрала кавычки и всё заработало.